# Displaying items in ListViews inside a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have a `List<CopyModel> copyData` with all my data, I want to display.
The CopyModel class looks like this:

```
public class CopyModel {
  public String autoId;
  public List<String> fieldNames;
  public List<Object> values;
}
```

I wanna display items of `fieldNames` and `values`.
**The exact data I get from FireStore**:

[image]

I'm displaying them in a **ListView**, with `simple_list_item_2`.
Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, copyData) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView t1 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            TextView t2 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

            String tS1 = copyData.get(position).fieldNames.get(position);
            t1.setText(tS1);

            String tS2 = String.valueOf(copyData.get(position).values.get(position));
            t2.setText(tS2);

            return view;
        }
    };
    holder.copyList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Current behavior**: The recyclerView is showing **3 ListViews** with:

- copyData0.fieldNames0 => "default"
- copyData0.values0 => "false"
- copyData1.fieldNames1 => "Pont"
- copyData1.fieldNames1 => "9"
- copyData1.fieldNames1 => "entity_name"
- copyData1.fieldNames1 => "Analízis pontok"

**How I want it to work**:
The **RecyclerView** would show as many lists as the size of `copyData` (in this case, 3), and each **ListView** would have as many rows as the size of its `fieldNames` (now it's 5, but can be any other)

**EDIT:**

```
    String tS1 = copyData.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).fieldNames.get(position);
    t1.setText(tS1);

    String tS2 = String.valueOf(copyData.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).values.get(position));
    t2.setText(tS2);
```

Now I'm getting the 3 seperate objects, in 3 seperate listview, but only the first 3 values from `fieldNames` and `values`

**EDIT#2**:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    for (int i = 0;i<copyData.size();i++) {
        final List<String> names = copyData.get(i).fieldNames;
        final List<Object> values = copyData.get(i).values;

        //noinspection unchecked
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, names) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView t1 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView t2 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                String tS1 = names.get(position);
                t1.setText(tS1);
                String tS2 = String.valueOf(values.get(position));
                t2.setText(tS2);

                return view;
            }
        };
        holder.copyList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This way I can add every fieldname-value pair to the list, but it behaves like, it goes over these 2 lines
 `final List<String> names = copyData.get(i).fieldNames;
  final List<Object> values = copyData.get(i).values;`
 3 times, then displays all the fieldname-value pairs of the last object in 3 seperate ListViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a First Glance I think problem is

```
 String tS1 = copyData.get(position).fieldNames.get(position);
```

Here you are using `position`  which is Listview's Adapters position . so your statement should

```
 String tS1 = copyData.get(Recycleview Adapter Position).fieldNames.get(Listview adapter position);
```

**From Your Edit:**

> Now I'm getting the 3 seperate objects, in 3 seperate listview, but
>   only the first 3 values

**Reason:**

Your First Adapter (Recyleview adapter) is running only three times.

If i understand your question . you need to do something like this:

1) set your Recycleview with list of `copyData` (which you are doing properly).

2) in `onBindViewHolder` of your recycleview. generate a full list of fieldNames and Values and Set your Listview Adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    YourCustomeListViewAdapter adapter = new YourCustomeListViewAdapter(younewlistwithfieldNamesandvalue)
        holder.copyList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

You are looping through copyData . which is wrong .

```
  for (int i = 0;i<copyData.size();i++)
```

you need to loop through fieldname and values array.like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
 for (int i = 0;i<copyData.get(position).fieldNames.size();i++) {
  }
 for (int i = 0;i<copyData.get(position).values.size();i++) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Recycleview Adapter Position is the "position" for me, this code is in my "CopyRecyclerViewAdapter.java" file, but I don't really know how should I get the adapter's position. Or if the "position" is the ListView adapter's posiiton, then how can i get the RecyclerView's posiiton?

Comment: @MátéAntal  You  are setting your `Listview's Adapter` inside `RecycleView's adapter` right ?

Comment: Do I need a whole custome adapter for this? I don't think I know how to write a custom adapter.  Can't I do it here with the ArrayAdapter? Plus in each CopyModel item I have two seperate Lists, one for fieldnames and one for values.

Comment: If I would "generate a full list of fieldNames and Values" then it would only show all of my names and values in one listview, right? We can't do that, its important that there should be as many ListViews as the size of copyData

Comment: @MátéAntal no you dont need custom adapter but for your understanding i wrote that. 2) you can generate one List with (name and value ) or two separate list .Its your choice.but the logic remain same

Comment: But the lists are already there, in the copyData (List<String fieldNames, and List<Object> values), just that those two are inside the big List<CopyModel>

Comment: @MátéAntal  you need to make full list (here it is only store 3 items )because your recycleview adapter runs only 3 time . So inside onBindView make new list (yo ucan use for loop for that )and set that list to listview

Comment: I think I almost got it, but run into another little problem, can you take a look on my edit?